# Prevent Chrome from executing Google Search when address bar content starts with //

Tags: google-chrome

I have a local server for development with addresses like "http://dev.local"

However when typing: "//dev.local", Chrome will search on Google instead of going to the specified address.

I need this to work for development purposes, is there a way to prevent Chrome from searching // URLs without disabling search from the address bar for all other inputs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a way to prevent Chrome from searching // URLs without disabling search from the address bar for all other inputs?

Yes. Add a trailing slash `/` like you would to any other local address to bypass searching Google, etc. e.g. `//dev.local/`.

Note that items accessed directly (e.g. `//dev.local/image.jpg`) should work correctly as-is (i.e. no trailing slash should be required).

Comment: Yeah, I was using this before also, not a bad idea as it's working with basic url names, however is it custom to also use this on a file? //dev.local/image.jpg/

Comment: @NaturalBornCamper no, this depends how the server handles the path provided... If it's static content, then this will not typically work. In this case it will try to resolve `/image.jpg/`, which could be a directory, a file, or even a path handled by an _active_ backend (e.g: PHP).

Comment: You're right, this works actually, I just hadn't tried with a domain that was set in my hosts file yet. Seems like if Chrome can reach the domain, it's not complaining for image files! Thanks friend!

Comment: You're welcome. Glad everything seems sorted out. =)

Answer (score 3):

URLs consist of multiple parts: ([wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL#Syntax))

```
scheme:[//[user[:password]@]host[:port]][/path][?query][#fragment]
```

As such, typing `//dev.local` doesn't fit into the pattern above, and the [omnibox](http://dev.chromium.org/user-experience/omnibox) will interpret this as a string to pass to a search engine.

You have three options:

- Be explicit - `http://dev.local` - always the best option
- Give an empty scheme - `://dev.local` - Chrome appears to default to `http`
- Give the bare hostname - `dev.local`

In the third case (with local DNS and Chrome's cooperation) you'll see something like this:

> In Chromium, we decided that consistency and speed was best, and given that the range of 'single-word inputs meant as searches' dwarfs the number of 'single-word inputs meant as URLs', we default to displaying web search results while doing a background DNS lookup to figure out if a local host exists - if it does, we display a "Did you mean `http://input/`" infobar as show below:

[image: chrome did you mean cheese]

Comment: Thanks for your comprehensive answer, I'll wait for a few days in case someone knows a hack before accepting :)

Comment: "_A hack_" is not something you should rely on... for anything.

Comment: For development, better than nothing ;)